# Css Rectangle that has triangle in the border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make a Rectangle In css , I want to make a triangle in the border of this Rectangle, but i don't know how to do it .

I need a Css code to make this :

[image]

How to do it in CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take this  [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/igoda)

```
<style>
        .rect {
            background: red;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .rect:after {
            content: "";
            background: #fff;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top:-35px;
            right: -25px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Rather than all that rotation and positioning, you could just put something in the top right with a linear gradient.

Comment: Since the `pseudo` is more supported than transform I'd suggest just using the `pseudo` instead of the transforms.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using only a pseudo whatever you like))

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `clip-path: polygon()` and give it the coords to clip... Read more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways to do this, you can use `before` and `after` css pseudos or you can use clip-path like mentioned from `hannesr`.

**CSS `before`**

```
.rect{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#f00;
  position:relative;
}
.rect:before{
  content:'';
  border-left:60px solid transparent;
  border-right:20px solid transparent;
  border-top:20px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-20px;
}
```

**CSS `Clip-Path`**

```
.rect2{
width:200px;
clip-path: polygon(0px 200px,20px 200px,10px 10px,40px 40px);
-webkit-clip-path:polygon(0px 200px,20px 200px,10px 10px,40px 40px);
height:200px;
background:#0f0;
position:relative;
}
```

Using clip-path different ways is fun, but remember it's like using the SVG so you need to know your coords. If you read anything read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/ which hannesr posted, it's very informative, and a lot of the html5 rocks website has great content.

**CSS `border-image`**

```
-webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
-o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 round;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

To try out the `before` and the `clip-path` follow this link  http://jsfiddle.net/2KTVX/

Also for browser compatibility for each of these please follow one of these links

[pseudo support](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent)

[Transform 2D](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

[Border Image](http://caniuse.com/border-image)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) can draw this background:

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 40px, red 40px);
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 40px, red 40px);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
</div>
```