# How to recreate this button border

Tags: css

I want to recreate the button and the border around the League of Legends [Play For Free button](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/).

The problem for me is recreating that border with the cut corners. I do not need the animations.

After inspecting their page elements, I could not find any elements responsible for them, and they do not seem to be using CSS to achieve this. I tried turning off a lot of the CSS, and they seem to persist on the page. Could someone please enlighten me on how they are making these borders, or how I can achieve this with pure CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css Rectangle that has triangle in the border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736683/css-rectangle-that-has-triangle-in-the-border)

Comment: They are using HTML canvas and javascript for the animation!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a button like the one in this example?
https://codepen.io/awesammcoder/pen/RYVwxa

```css
body {
background: #333;
}

.button {
font-size: 12pt;
color: white;
background: transparent;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 3px solid white;
margin: 20px;
position: relative;
letter-spacing: 1px;
outline: none;
}

.button:before {
content: '';
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #333;
border: 3px solid white;
transform: rotate(45deg);
position: absolute;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
top: -12px;
left: -13px;
}

.button:after {
content: '';
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #333;
border: 3px solid white;
transform: rotate(-132deg);
position: absolute;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
top: auto;
right: -13px;
bottom: -12px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Play now</button>
```